# Legal hurdles to providing personalized service based on protected demographics?

Tags: united-states, internet, discrimination

I am a computer scientist and UI/UX designer working on a fun project - perfect interface discrimination. Essentially, in the same vein as perfect price discrimination, I want to create a system that provides the perfect interface for people based on their demographic information. Some of these demographics, such as sex and age, are legally protected, and thus the question focuses on those in particular.

The use of this would follow as such:

1. User enters system
2. System magically detects demographic information such as age and sex (the latter of which is a protected class) (how doesn't matter for the question, just assume that it is 100% legal)
3. System provides interface that we know appeals more to User's demographics

What it does not do:

1. Prevent user from accessing any services the business provides
2. Make it unduly difficult for User to access any services

I know there are legal problems with providing different prices under 15 U.S. Code § 13, which prevents prices from discriminating for the purpose of lessening competition. However, I cannot find anything regarding using different interfaces for the same purpose, and definitely nothing on using demographics to tailor these interfaces.

Are there any legal requirements for providing the same experience based on protected demographics? I seem to recall department stores being able to lay out men's and women's sections differently, but does that apply here?

Note: I know that if there isn't a law banning it, then it is allowed in the US. I'm just seeking the help of people better able to know what to look for.

Comment: It sounds like this is basically a marketing gimmick, and you're allowed to target marketing based on sex.

Comment: @Luck Ok cool! If you want to add that as an answer I can accept it!